# Does state update of parent component assures remount of child component in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let us suppose we have a parent component:

```js
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      titleState: undefined
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    // import Title string from JSON in order to assign it to titleState

    this.setState({ titleState: jsonResponse["title"] });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ChildComponent title={this.state.titleState} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h>Title is: {this.props.title}</h>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Let us suppose server response with title comes with a significant delay so that in the beginning what we see on the screen is:

```
Title is:
```

But when response comes with jsonResponse["title"] value: "Bone Collector"
we see:

```
Title is: Bone Collector
```

Now the question is:

Is it guaranteed that the state change in Parent Component will cause the Child Component to be rerendered so that is is updated with new ParentComponent's state via props?

Comment: See the answers please and explain to those who answer why you think they are wrong. Thank you.

Comment: the answers below are only applicable only for initial state change, but later at any instance  or events if the state of parent updates than child will not re-render.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React applies `diffing algorithm` to see difference between both `trees`. 
When a component updates, the instance stays the same, so that state is maintained across renders. React updates the props of the underlying component instance to match the new element, and calls `componentWillReceiveProps()` and `componentWillUpdate()` on the underlying instance.

In your case, since `prop` passed to `childComponent` is changed, child component will be re-rendered with `new prop value`. However, react will apply `diffing algorithm` on `old rendered output` of child component and `new rendered output` and will only update what has changed.

To satisfy your curiosity, read : https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html

Answer (score 1):

Specifically speaking about your code snippent in the post.

**Yes.** It is guaranteed that the state change in Parent Component will cause the Child Component to be rerendered.

Now the question's are,

**Why the child component will get update with new values?**

Because, it is bind in a way that whenever values in parent change's, it will compare ([The Diffing Algorithm](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html)) the `new tree` with `old tree` and identifies what has changed and patches only changed part in a tree.

```
<h>Title is: {this.props.title}</h>
```

**When does it not update the child component?**

Whenever you are getting `props` from parent and store them in child's `state`, and using `state` values as your data source, like:

```
state ={
   title: this.props.title
}


<h>Title is: {this.state.title}</h>
```

Now in this case, data source is `state`. Which will get set only once when child component `mounts`. Whenever `state` changes in parent component, your child component is not aware of any `props` changes and in result your child component will  not get updated with new values.

To make this scenario work, will need a life cycle method called `componentDidUpdate`, where we can set new `props` into `state` and then as state changes your child component will get re-render.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
   if(prevProps.title !== this.props.title){
      this.setState({title: this.props.title})
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you call `setState()` in `componentWillMount()` of the `Parent` then it will not *re-render* the `Child` but use that value during the *initial render* of the `Child` component and ignore the value you set initially in the parent constructor.

As per the React docs:

> UNSAFE_componentWillMount() is invoked just before mounting occurs. It
>   is called before render(), therefore calling setState() synchronously
>   in this method will not trigger an extra rendering. Generally, we
>   recommend using the constructor() instead for initializing state.

But if you invoke `setState()` asynchronously the state of the `Parent` will be updated and by your code the props sent to the `Child` component will be changed, thus triggering a re-render of the `Child` component.

But it is highly unadvisable to do API calls from `UNSAFE_componentWillMount` instead, do the API calls from `componentDidMount()` of your `Parent` component.

This simple example will help you understand this:

```js
class Parent extends React.Component{
   constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {foo: "first"};
    }
   UNSAFE_componentWillMount(){
      this.setState({foo: "second"}); //ignore the initial state value
      setTimeout(() => this.setState({foo: "third"}), 5000); 
   }
   render(){
     return <Child foo={this.state.foo}></Child>
   }
}

class Child extends React.Component{
   constructor(props){
      super(props);
   }
  
  render(){
    console.log("Child rendered", this.props.foo);
    return <div>This is the Child</div>
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Parent/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

In the above snippet, `Child rendered first` is not seen in the console, because the `setState()` was called in the `componentWillMount()` which overwrote the `foo` property of the `state` from `first` to `second`.

This is because `componentWillMount()` is invoked immediately before mounting occurs so there is no chance of re-render, but the initial render will use the data of the `state` set in the `componentWillMount()`.